# Twitter Bootstrap collapsible sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to ask how to create a this kind of side bar. Take a look at this link.

http://utopiaadmin.themio.net/dashboard.html

(Left Side Navigation) Its a fluid layout using twitter bootstrap, and also its collapsible. There are 3 collapsible steps in this admin panel for Left Side Navigation.

1. Icons, Texts for (desktop, laptops etc.)
2. Icons (tablets, ipad etc.)
3. Collapsible list (mobile phones)

I tried to figure how to do this kind of fluid, collapsible sidebar. But still I'm not able to. So, If anyone know how to do this using twitter bootstrap, please let me know.

Comment: Bootstrap makes use of [media queries](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) for it's responsive layouts.

Comment: Cool. So how to collapse using media queries ? Is there any good tutorials ?

Answer (score 1):

HUH... finally managed to find out. Thanks a lot @Ross

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.